# Can I Cut Folders in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm now using wxWidgets 3.2 to build a small app. And I need to cut some folders to another path. I've found that wxWidgets has some function named wxCopyFile, but it can only copy files. Copying takes more time when moving files in the same disk. Is There a function in wxWidgets that can cut(move) folders?
Thanks.

I've searched in wxWidgets' official documents, but I haven't found anything useful. I'm not sure if I'm too careless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wxRename with old and new path as arguments.
https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/group__group__funcmacro__crt.html#ga5cd9c7d46f3f90bde0c925c16518d3ee